# Do I still need this @types/react-router-dom package when using v6 of react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am confused about these two packages.
I am making a new Typescript project.

The thing is that
In my previous projects I install `react-router-dom` and `@types/react-router-dom` for typescript support.

But right now when `react-router-dom` v6 comes out.

`@types/react-router-dom` package doesn't seem to be updated anymore. Do I still need to install this one? Will it work fine without it?

Comment: No, `react-router@6` is written in Typescript so there's no external typings package necessary.

Answer (score 10):

`react-router-dom` **v6** and above is written in typescript, so no you don't need to install  `@types/react-router-dom`.